# transimpedance op-amp wrong and random output

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc, single-supply-op-amp, virtual-ground

> > from my previous question ([this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386399/dividing-voltage-of-shunt-vref-lm4040/386401#386401)) i advised to using
> >     operational amplifiers to converting current changes to voltage
> >     changes then i followed the standard circuit for a transimpedance
> >     operation of amplifier with a piece of **TLC272CP** which you can see
> >     how i wired it : 
> >  [image]

my aim is measuring IR, so i connected a photodiode to the op-amp, i tried single supply because i cant make bipolar supplies +/-, then i create a virtual ground by simply dividing resistors to get a mid rail voltage between VDD(<sub>5v</sub>) and GND. then connect output (also divided) to an ADC.

unfortunately resaults from ADC are some random noises and IR does not affect them even a bit!!! they are near to 2.5 volt without **output division**.

also i disconnected +input of opamp (PIN3) from VGND and connected it to the physical GND but still sense less to IR, just get lower noises.

---

i think my circuit is just follow standards, so what could be wrong with it.

Comment: TLC272C is a dual op-amp. What did you do with the amplifier not being used for your TIA?

Comment: @ThePhoton, most opamp's are dual or quad! google is full of tutorials for TIA, they never pointed any thing about problem of dual amps

Comment: You have to apply a (usually reverse) bias voltage to the photodiode in order to get the photocurrent out. Connect the anode to real ground (not VGnd), and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @SvenB i connected photodiode anode to real groubd and then just get 80% of vcc sense less to IR

Comment: @SvenB excuse me, it works after connecting anode to gnd, the reason i dont sence any thing was the bad offset of resaults, after changing 1M to 100K outputs starts from 520(2.55v) goes to 814(3.97) of total 1024(5v) it stills bad, any idea?

Comment: @SvenB may you please post this comment as an answer

Comment: @payam_sbr, an unused op-amp can cause problems. See [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1957), [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204/sboa204.pdf), or [here](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-46.html).

Comment: What is your photodiode?

Comment: @laptop2d i used an unknown 5mm photodiode, but i can replace it with **PH320**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A photodiode is meant to be used with a bias voltage. This is typically achieved by using the "virtual short-circuit" of the input pins of the opamp in the TIA.

Like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJTJE5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The *best* way to improve the output signal strength is to get more light on the photodiode.
You can also try increasing the feedback resistance at the expense of stability. If stability is an issue, you can add a feedback capacitance to make it stable again, unfortunately at the expense of bandwidth.

Comment: It's entirely possible to operate this circuit with 0 bias on the photodiode. This is called photovoltaic mode, and generally results in lower noise but also lower bandwidth. There is also an effect on responsivity but it is not a large effect.